# input multiple characters in single line

Tags: java, string, char

I want to enter a certain number of characters. Rather than entering one at a time, I want to make it so that I can enter multiple characters on a single line(.For example, a b y f).

I thought of making input a single string and then trimming it but I could not do it. please help.

Comment: Can you show the code where you tried to do that?

Comment: Have you tried something like `String[] inputChars = inputLine.split(" ");`?